# What is the simplest way to get hierarchical page URLs with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url, hierarchy

How do I get the page structure showing up in URLs?

If I have pages and their parent page structured something like

```
+-Home
+-Fruits
+--Apple
+--Banana
+-Vegetables
+--Salad
+--Tomatoes
```

and I want URLs like

```
/fruits/apple
/vegetables/salad
```

what is the best way to get that with Wordpress?

I do not mean custom menus, I mean page hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to activate [Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks)

Comment: Activating permalinks is not my problem, how to get them hierarchical is the question.

Comment: Wordpress page structure is already hierarchical, you can select a parent for each page, permalinks will reflect this structure.

Comment: More specifically, if you select Custom Structure under Permalink Settings page and add /%postname% to the end this will generate the requested URL